# How can I enable in-game live "net worth" or GPM stats in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

How can I enable in-game live "net worth" or GPM stats in Dota 2?
I see that on some YT videos of the gameplay.
Is that a setting? Or is that a plugin/addon?

This question is similar, but was not really answered:
[Console command to show gpm or total gold collected on DOTA 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313238/console-command-to-show-gpm-or-total-gold-collected-on-dota-2)

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about these statistics

[image: dota plus stats]

You need to purchase [Dota Plus](https://www.dota2.com/plus) they are a part of the [Plus Assistant](https://www.dota2.com/plus#PlusAssistant) features.

[image: real time stats]